# Json.net DeserializeObject issue

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using JSON.Net to try and deserialize some responses from facebook. Here's a snapshot of the data I'm reading in:

```
 {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "123"
        },
        {
          "id": "234"
        }
      ],
      "paging": {
        "cursors": {
          "before": "xxx",
          "after": "xxx"
        },
        "next": "xxx"
      }
 }
```

classes:

```
class jsonDeserialize
{
    public List<ListDetail> ListDetail { get; set; }
}

public class DataList
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class Paging
{
    public List<string> cursors { get; set; }
    public string next { get; set; }
}
public class Cursors
{
    public string before { get; set; }
    public string after { get; set; }
}

public class ListDetail
{
    public List<Cursors> Cursors { get; set; }
    public List<Paging> Articles { get; set; }
    public List<DataList> DataList { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using this code to use the JSON.NET Deserialize function:
for some reason, result return null, please help me :(

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonDeserialize>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your classes defenition:

```
    class jsonDeserialize
    {
        public List<DataList> data { get; set; }
        public Paging paging { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataList
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Paging
    {
        public Cursors cursors { get; set; }
        public string next { get; set; }
    }
    public class Cursors
    {
        public string before { get; set; }
        public string after { get; set; }
    }
```

`jsonDeserialize` contains list of DataList, `ListDetail` can me removed, `cursors` is not an array, it's an object.

Answer (score 0):

*Omg, I've missed it is JSON from facebook and "solved" reversed problem. I'll keep it here, though, just in case*

First, as quick remark, your deserialization code here must look smth like `var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`**`<jsonDeserialize>`**`(jsonString);`

Your JSON does not correspond to code.
If you want deserialize to jsonDeserialize class your json must look like that 
(pay close attention to `[]` and `{}`)

```
{
  "ListDetail" : 
  [
   {
     "Cursors":
     [
       {
         "before" : "value",
         "after" : "value"
       }

      ],
      "Articles":
      [
        {
          "Cursors":
          [

            "cursor1",
            "cursor2"

          ],
          "next" : "somenext"
        }
      ],
      "DataList":
      [
        {
          "id" : "someid"
        },
        {
          "id" : "someid2"
        }
      ]
   }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 class jsonDeserialize
    {

        public List<DataList> data { get; set; }
        public Paging paging { get; set; }

    }

    public class DataList
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Paging
    {
        public Cursors cursors { get; set; }
        public string next { get; set; }
    }
    public class Cursors
    {
        public string before { get; set; }
        public string after { get; set; }
    }

var result=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonDeserialize>(jsonformat.Substring(0,jsonformat.Length));
```

Use it it will give you write result. beacuse data and paging treated as properties so that you need to intialize those properties in your class jsondeserailized and instead of list use cursors because you storing cursors data in paging class .Thanks